# Diffusion of responsibility between different departments

Tags: professionalism, communication

I work in a call center. My position is tech support for clients. Sometimes when I transfer a call to another department I get a lot of push back and the receiver does not want to accept the call. The company has a loose policy to "own the call" and try to avoid doing transfers as this leads to a better customer experience and in theory we were at least minimally trained to do every role (for example I had basic billing and sales training).

The company sells cable services, including television. I don't watch TV and when a client asked to help them decide which channels to purchase based on some criteria (specifically sports), I transferred to sales. The agent asked why I couldn't do it and I said I could technically but since I don't watch TV wasn't sure what to recommend. He asked for my agent id which is a sure sign he's going to try to get me in trouble. I think the thing is some sales are comissionable and others are not.

I've never been given official guidelines on when or who to transfer to. Everyone has an intuitive idea what people in the "sales", "loyalty" "billing" etc. but things go wrong (e.g. loyalty refuses the call as "technically the client hasn't said he will cancel his contract").

I emailed my manager asking for clarification but she hasn't replied. She is also of the mindset "not to give specific targets/details because the expectation is for us to do the best we can do".

How can I get more clarification? At the end of the day, is the only important thing what my manager thinks and I shouldn't worry about if the receiving agent rather not take the call? Is anything I said out of line? For example I could have researched information about what tv channels have sports on them but to me this seems like sale's job. If someone asks for my agent id again should I say "I'll give it to you but if there's a problem can we try to resolve it ourselves?"

Answer (score 6):

It probably pays for you to learn more about the product you're supporting.  Being on the receiving end of phone calls like this, you're going to face this kind of situation (where you're not fully conversant with the specific information the customer needs to know).

So, any time you need to transfer a call to someone else, ask yourself whether you could have handled that call given more knowledge.  Then put the research in to fill this gap in your knowledge.

If someone asks for your agent ID, I'd say you should give it.  Customers tend to get irritated when their questions aren't answered.  Follow your standard operating procedure in this instance.

Also, talk to your more experienced co-workers and ask what they do in these circumstances.

Comment: I thought he meant the "sales agent" not the "client", who ask for his agent ID.

Comment: I'd generally assume that someone asking for an agent ID would be the customer intending/threatening to make a complaint.  I suspect that internal transfers are logged "for training purposes".

Comment: I did mean it was the agent I transferred to who asked for my agent ID (to get me in trouble, though nothing has come of it)

Answer (score 0):

> My position is tech support for clients.

...and...

> ...a client asked to help them decide which channels to purchase

Don't really go together in my book. Sure, there's some borderline cases you could argue are tech support in one case, and sales in another, but this seems a pretty clear cut sales call to me, and nothing to do with tech support.

> For example I could have researched information about what tv channels have sports on them but to me this seems like sale's job.

So yes, I quite agree with the above, and I would push from that clarification from your manager. However, if you are expected to deal with these calls, then I think that's just going to be the approach you have to take - research on the fly as best you can, and give the best advise you can based on that. Eventually you'll likely build up your knowledge this way to the point where you can answer most common cases without doing much/any on the fly research, which will make things considerably easier.